# assign alias to long reference names inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to be able to assign an alias to a long reference name inside an ng-repeat directive.

Right now I have 2 complex objects, one acts as a kind of grouped index for the other. The ng-repeat template code works fine but it is becoming very difficult to read and I dread the thought of returning to it in a few months time.

If possible, I would like convert **something like this**:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in apples">
    <div>
        <span>Type</span>
        <span>{{a.category[1].information.type}}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        Don't you just love <span>{{a.category[1].information.type}}</span> apples. 
        My granny says {{a.category[1].information.type}} apples are the best kind. 
        I would pick {{a.category[1].information.type}} over {{apples[0].category[1].information.type}} apples any day of the week.
    </div>
</div>
```

into **something like this**

```
<div ng-repeat="a in apples"
     ng-example-assign="ta = a.category[1].information.type">
    <div>
        <span>Type</span>
        <span>{{ta}}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        Don't you just love <span>{{ta}}</span> apples. 
        My granny says {{ta}} apples are the best kind. 
        I would pick {{ta}} over {{apples[0].category[1].information.type}} apples any day of the week.
    </div>

</div>
```

The `ng-example-assign` directive I made up for this example. Can anyone tell me if something like this is possible using angular or ng-repeat? It may be that I need to rethink the code but I thought I would ask here first. TIA!

Comment: Very naive implementation.  http://jsfiddle.net/kgc0dL6e/.

Comment: Thanks javaCity. I ran into the same echoing problem when I tried to assign it directly as you have done. This is nice but not as nice as ng-init!

Comment: That is true. I knew this wasn't proper way that's why I put it in the comments :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ng-init for this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="s in data" ng-init="address = s.address">
        {{ address }}
     </div>
</div>
```

**jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/5yfgLgr9/2/

Comment: I really thought that ngInit was pretty useless (esp. for loading data into controllers) but I see now from the documentation that this example is the only appropriate use of ngInit. Thanks again. My templates look **much** cleaner already.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: @chriskelly I actually end up using nginit more than the docs recommend. For some small event handling, it lets you do a lot without additional js -- obviously it's easy to abuse... so beware.

Answer (score 1):

Using a directive with isolated scope it would be fairly straightforward.

Template HTML

```
<div assign="ta" source="data[0].items[0].subitems[0]">
```

Directive

```
app.directive('assign',function(){
  return {
    scope:{'assign':'@', "source": '='},
    templateUrl: 'testTemplate',
    link:function(scope){
      scope[scope.assign]=scope.source;
    }
  }
});
```

generally a good idea to avoid naming custom directives with `ng` to avoid possible conflicts with upgrades or third party modules that might also use them

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/fIBP8Z2zMnoZlcYqYeBf?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: This works and seems to be pretty flexible. However, I think the ng-init solution provided by Daniel is a simpler so I will accept that. I will avoid using ng in directive names :D. Thanks!

Comment: actually I agree about `ng-init`...it never crosssed my mind, much simpler and no isolated scope